# Expand All / Collapse All Accordion using addEventListener

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener, expand

I’m using a css & js accordion from w3schools. Now I’m trying to modify it to be able to expand all / collapse all.

Problem:
It uses addEventListener to register the click on an element.
If I use a separate function to exp all and have one accordion element already open, it closes that one because the js toggles the open / close. I’ve tried setting a variable to true / false for when elements are individually clicked but no success.

Any ideas for how to make this work to expand / collapse all?

Rather than pasting the code, here’s the example at w3schools:

https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_accordion_symbol

Thanks,
Ove

Comment: What is the problem here? The expand-all button needs to add the class 'active' while the  collapse-all button needs to remove it. Don't toggle the class, since that will just flip the state, as you've already discovered. `element.classList.add('active')` and `element.classList.remove('active')`

Comment: Thank you, I was trying too hard to make the expand / collapse part of the same function, but you steered me right and I ended up creating a separate function using your suggestion. Worked great. Thank you

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: All the code is in the working example link in the original post. I thought it would be more complete with an already working example.